# Twig - hook into the "for" loop and execute php function

Tags: php, twig

Is there any way to hook into the for loop to send the current "*context*" (data) to php?

**My use case is as follows**:

I am busy with a complicated setup that renders lots of "*mini*" templates (sometimes nestled) each template needs to have access to its parent's "*data*" (if nestled). So I was thinking of something like hook into the for loop and assign a function to it.

I am aware I could add a custom tag or function and do something like

`{% for row in ['yada','who'] %} {{ row|context() }} {{ row }} {% endfor %}`

But I'm hoping to do it in the background without adding anything to the for loop. (custom templates get used)

Comment: don't understand what you're trying to achieve yet. exactly *what* is using the context? any function you define can get the context, see:  https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/advanced.html#context-aware-filters (it works the same for functions)

Comment: You could create your own `For`-tag based on the existing one and change the compilation of the `PHP` from there out

Comment: @jakumi the idea is that the "page" gets made up of a template with placeholders. when the template gets rendered it uses specific templates depending on where  it is going to be like for instance front end / back end / form etc. but you can for instance include another "item" inside an "item". the nestled item needs to have access to its parents `data` as in `{% for data in records %}`. my idea is to create a context array which i can tap into on rendering. but right now im stuck setting it up without the hook into the `for` loop.

@DarkBee yeah was thinking the same. wanted to avoid it tho

Comment: think the terminology is a bit misleading. i dont need twig context. i need a hook to run a function on ever "for" loop item. ignore the word "context"

Comment: you could do the "dirty stuff" outside of twig and nicely prepare the array/vars you go over? unless of course there's to much to possible go over. but you could "enrich" your array at least

Comment: @Jakumi OP wants to hook every `for`-loop in `Twig`, if he did it outside his controller it would mean he had to write/call the code for every collection he wants to loop

Comment: @DarkBee I'm quite sure he asks that, possibly even wants that. I just question the approach ... . the answer to the question is obviously to hack the for-block. doesn't that sound wrong somehow? it is as if he wants to loop over a set of items, but instead of those items, they should be something else. that's why I suggest pre-processing to make them into something else before looping in the template. ultimately, a template engine is not meant to be ultra smart, but do simple things. hiding stuff - in my opinion - will cause more harm in the long run.

Comment: right now im trying to pre-process with "ancestors". changing my entire codebase to enable it. not too keen to redo the for loop and bring in other tags for it. was really hoping there was an extends for type function somewhere. tried checking the source code but alas there is not as far as i can see.

i can get the full data for the "parent" easily enough. just not the data in the for loop. so im trying to do an offset type thing.